# Drupal 7 API endpoint I get a 404 "Invalid URL path."

Tags: api, drupal-7, http-status-code-404, endpoint

I am trying to create an API endpoint in Drupal 7 and followed a tutorial in https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/rest-easy-part-1-and-restful-you/

My folder structure:

sites/all/modules/custom/myresteasy_api/myresteasy_api.info
sites/all/modules/custom/myresteasy_api/myresteasy_api.module
sites/all/modules/custom/myresteasy_api/plugins/restful/node/artists/0.1/artist__0_1.inc
sites/all/modules/custom/myresteasy_api/plugins/restful/node/artists/0.1/ResteasyRestfulEntityArtistsResource.class.php

The module was listed in the admin section and I have activated it but when I access my API endpoint (/api/v0.1/artists) I get a 404 "Invalid URL path."

Comment: I use services module to create my api : https://www.drupal.org/project/services

Comment: @Fky Thanks bro I figured out some other tutorial to get that, but I am curious to know what am doing wrong in this tuts because I have spent more than 2 hours on that.